# CASE condition and how to code it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a column in a new table( Table B) called Number of different locations. This column is derived from two columns in a Table A - Customer and Location.

Sample Data from Table A .

```
Customer          Location 

Mr James Smith   Los Angeles
Mr David Jones   London
Mr James Smith   Paris
```

So the pseudo code ?

```
[Number of Different Locations] =

CASE 
When Customer has more than one location ( count greater than 1 of for distinct customer) 
Then populate those entries as 'Y'
Else 'N'
```

Now I have tried a few ways to code the 1st condition but it does not work .

```
CASE 
When EXISTS ( select distinct customer, count ( Location ) from Table B
              group by customer)
then 'Y'
Else 'N'
```

What am I doing wrong ? All the values are coming out in resultant table as 'Y'

Comment: You need where clause on your existing and it is to no use having a distinct in an exist statement

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   Customer, Location, [Number of different locations] = 
      CASE 
      When EXISTS ( select distinct customer, count ( Location ) from Table B
              group by customer
               having count(location)>1)
then 'Y'
Else 'N'
      END
FROM [Table]
```

you didn't specify  "Having > 1"

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a separate subselect for that. This can be handled entirely within a `GROUP BY` clause and using the count of locations to determine if there are multiple locations.

```
SELECT Customer
       ,  MultipleLocations = 
            CASE WHEN COUNT(Location) > 1 
                 THEN 'Y' 
                 ELSE 'N'        
            END 
FROM   YourTable
GROUP BY
       Customer
```

Should your table contain multiple records for a customer with the same location, you can add a `DISTINCT` clause to accomodate for this.

```
SELECT Customer
       ,  MultipleLocations = 
            CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Location) > 1 
                 THEN 'Y' 
                 ELSE 'N'        
            END 
FROM   YourTable
GROUP BY
       Customer
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help did it in another way:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
    (
        Customer VARCHAR(100),
        Location VARCHAR(100)
    )
INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 'Mr James Smith','Los Angeles'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mr David Jones','London'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mr James Smith','Paris'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.Customer) AS NbrOf,
        tbl.Customer,
        tbl.Location
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT
    CTE.Customer,
    CTE.Location,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN CTE.NbrOf>1
            THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END
    ) AS newColumn
FROM
    CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TableA 
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ('Mr James Smith', 'Los Angeles'),
                     ('Mr David Jones', 'London'),
                     ('Mr James Smith', 'Paris')
             ) AS T (Customer, Location)
     ), 
     TableACustomerTallies
     AS
     (
      SELECT Customer, COUNT(DISTINCT Location) AS Tally
        FROM TableA
       GROUP 
          BY Customer

     )
SELECT Customer, 
        'Y' AS HasMultipleLocations
  FROM TableACustomerTallies
 WHERE Tally > 1
UNION
SELECT Customer, 
        'N' AS HasMultipleLocations
  FROM TableACustomerTallies
 WHERE Tally <= 1;
```